# Stripe shows balance more than transferred amount

Tags: java, spring, stripe-payments

I have two stripe connected accounts and I transferred test credit to one account. the transferred amount is `180 USD` and the total amount is `200 USD`. here is the java side code to transfer the amount.

```
    for (Transaction transaction: paymentRequest.getTransactions()) {
        TransferCreateParams transferParams =
                    TransferCreateParams.builder()
                            .setAmount((long)transaction.getAmount().doubleValue()*100)
                            .setCurrency(obj.get().getBaseCurrency())
                            .setDestination(obj.get().getStripeAccountId())
                            .setTransferGroup(transferGroup)
                            .build();

            Transfer transfer = Transfer.create(transferParams);
    }
```

below is what I sent from the front end.

```
{
"chargeToken": "tok_1K3zdzIGcHfAoRtZLxzlv56B",
"order": {
    "totalPrice": {
        "amount": 200,
        "currency": "USD"
    }
},
"transactions": [
    {
        "id": "85a63a05-08b4-4e8c-9c57-78a3e80ca32c",
        "amount": 180
    }
]}
```

here is the payment details data of stripe side

[image: here is the payment details data of stripe side]

but when I check on the connected account section it shows `181.30 USD`.

[image]

I don't know how is it happened. hope your support to resolve this. thank you!

Comment: This looks like something that should be taken up with Stripe's developer support (if there is such a thing).

Comment: The likely cause of this is FX rates. The presentment currency for the charge was `USD`. This charge was converted to `EUR`  as (I'm assuming) your account does not have an external `USD` (bank) account and therefore cannot accept `USD` balances. You set `currency: 'USD'` on the transfer and, as your platform does not have a `USD` balance, it would have been drawn (with applicable FX) from your `EUR` balance. There's details on this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/currencies).

Answer (score 0):

okay, I got the answers from stripe support. And thanks for getting clarified the matter!

```
This behavior is due to the currency conversion and is expected. The value shown on the connected account list ($181.30) is an estimate when the platform and connected account currencies are different. You should use financial reports for reconciliation or reporting purposes, to know exactly how much an account has processed.

Here is how the value was derived for this testmode account:
1. We take the volume in the connected account currency (in this case, EUR260.27)
2. We convert it to use using a pinned exchange rate (currently, exchange rate as of 2021-10-05)
3. We arrive at USD 301.80

We use a pinned exchange rate to ensure that the balance/volume is consistent with what we're querying from the system that powers the filtering on this page, which is typically delayed.

Again, this does not mean that you transferred an extra $1.80 to the connected account.
```